# split a multi page pdf file of mixed content into multiple images

Tags: imagemagick

How do i split a multi page pdf file of mixed content into multiple images jpg or png.

The pdf contents have text, images, lines, etc. which all needs to be converted into list of images.

I tried

```
convert -trim a.pdf -resize 50% -quality 100 -sharpen 0x1.0 a
```

the pdf has 25 pages. But the above command doesn't split the pdf and text are not converted into images .

Comment: try `convert a.pdf -trim +repage -resize 50% -quality 100 -sharpen 0x1.0 a.jpg`

Comment: can we have file names as a001.jpg  rather than a-1.jpg

Comment: `convert a.pdf -trim +repage -resize 50% -quality 100 -sharpen 0x1.0 a.jpg` should by default list multipage pdf files as a-0.jpg, a-1.jpg ... a-N.jpg.  You can put leading zeros by `convert a.pdf -trim +repage -resize 50% -quality 100 -sharpen 0x1.0 a-%03d.jpg` to make for example a-000.jpg, a-001.jpg ...